# Running Fat jar and getting path not found exception in SBT

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, sbt, executable-jar

I have a scala project which is referring to a file created in the src/main/resources/MyFile.csv.

I created a fat jar and following is my build.sbt

```
name := "my-project"

version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.7",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.7"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF","services",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case PathList("META-INF",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

But when I try running my fat jar I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Path does not exist:
> file:/path/to/myProject/target/scala-2.11/src/main/resources/MyFile.csv

I am using the following command to run the jar

```
java -cp myProject.jar com.organization.myProject
```

Is there a way to include my file/folder paths in the build.sbt file?

**UPDATE**

I changed my build.sbt as follows

```
 name := "my-project"
    
    version := "0.1"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
    
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.7",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.7"
    )
    
   scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "main"

    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF","services",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case PathList("META-INF",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

But its still giving the path not found exception. Anybody have an idea?